# Django app NameError however the app is installed

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-settings, django-apps

I'm trying to modify Django's built-in authetnication system by adding a custom user model. The customized model is defined inside an app  named `accounts`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

COUNTRIES = settings.COUNTRY_CHOICES

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    zip_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=64)
    address_street = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=64)
    address_number = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, choices=COUNTRIES, max_length=8)
```

I updated the `settings.py` file this way:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = accounts.CustomUser
```

I added `accounts` as an installed app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'store',
    'cart',
]
```

When I try to run the `python manage.py makemigrations` command in terminal to apply changes made to the user model Django's throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\Dev\ecommerce\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\Dev\ecommerce\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\.virtualenvs\ecommerce-vU6zMECh\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line        
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\.virtualenvs\ecommerce-vU6zMECh\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\.virtualenvs\ecommerce-vU6zMECh\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\.virtualenvs\ecommerce-vU6zMECh\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\.virtualenvs\ecommerce-vU6zMECh\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\uhlar\Dev\ecommerce\config\settings.py", line 149, in <module>
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = accounts.CustomUser
NameError: name 'accounts' is not defined
```

The error is not only confined to the `accounts` app, no matter inside which app I try to define the `CustomUser` model I'm still getting it.

If anyone knows what's causing the problem please help me to resolve it.

Comment: It looks like your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is defined as `AUTH_USER_MODEL = accounts.MyUser`, not `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"` (a string).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I accidentally attached a previous error message (where I used the name ```MyUser``` for my class but changed to ```CustomUser``` since then). But it's still not working, I guess the focus is more on the ```NameError: name 'accounts' is not defined``` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) should be a *string*, not a (qualified) name, so:

```
# settings.py

# …

#  string literal 🖟                   🖟
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Willem mentioned, you need to update your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting inside `settings.py` to  `accounts.CustomerUser` model. In addition, you will have to update your schema manually as when you first run migrations, Django will use the default `auth.User` for multiple foreign keys etc. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) for changing a user mid project.